# SVG pattern not visible only on Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

My pattern is in Firefox not visible:

Top: Chrome

[image]

Bottom: Firefox

[image]

**Svg Code (but please down a bit to see the image)**

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:none;}
     .st1{opacity:0.48;}
     .st2{fill:#FFF99A;}
     .st5{fill:url(#a);stroke:#007BFF;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <pattern id="b" y="120" width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 -200 200 200">
      <rect class="st0" y="-200" width="200" height="200"/>
      <rect class="st0" y="-200" width="200" height="200"/>
      <g class="st1">
       <rect class="st2" y="-100" width="200" height="100"/>
      </g>
      <g class="st1">
       <rect class="st2" x="100" y="-200" width="100" height="200"/>
      </g>
    </pattern>
     
    <pattern id="a" xlink:href="#b" patternTransform="matrix(.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -16028 -559.29)">
    </pattern>
    
    <path class="st5" d="m87.5 87.5v23.1c0 3.5-2.6 6.4-6.1 6.8-21.7 2.6-42.3 0-50.3-1.2-2.1-0.3-3.6-2.1-3.6-4.2 0-5.6 0.1-16.7 0.5-24.4h23.5"/>
    
    </svg>
```

Any idea why?

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929731/svg-pattern-inconsistency-between-chrome-and-firefox), but it really didn't change anything.

Comment: Firefox nightlies now display this correctly. This fix should be part of the Firefox 114 release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the pattern `#a`and now it works in FF too

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" version="1.1" viewBox="0 70 120 65" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
     .st0{fill:none;}
     .st1{opacity:0.48;}
     .st2{fill:#FFF99A;}
     .st5{fill:url(#b);stroke:#007BFF;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    </style>
    <pattern id="b" y="120" width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 200 200" patternTransform="matrix(.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -16028 -559.29)">
      <rect class="st0"  width="200" height="200"/>
      <rect class="st0"  width="200" height="200"/>
      <g class="st1">
       <rect class="st2" y="100" width="200" height="100"/>
      </g>
      <g class="st1">
       <rect class="st2" x="100"  width="100" height="200"/>
      </g>
    </pattern>
     
    
    
    <path class="st5" d="m87.5 87.5v23.1c0 3.5-2.6 6.4-6.1 6.8-21.7 2.6-42.3 0-50.3-1.2-2.1-0.3-3.6-2.1-3.6-4.2 0-5.6 0.1-16.7 0.5-24.4h23.5"/>
    
    </svg>
```

Comment: actually you changed some parts quite a bit. I'm trying to figure out why it works with your example and not mine. If I find it out you get the accepted status of course

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in Firefox that affects patterns with viewBox x,y values that aren't 0 0.

So to fix this SVG replace the y value from the pattern's viewBox with 0 (`viewBox="0 -200 200 200"` -> `viewBox="0 0 200 200"`), and wrap the pattern contents in `<g transform="translate(0, 200)">` which offsets the viewBox change.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 120 120" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 120 120" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;}
    .st1{opacity:0.48;}
    .st2{fill:#FFF99A;}
    .st5{fill:url(#a);stroke:#007BFF;stroke-width:0.5;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<!-- remove negative -200 from viewBox -->
<pattern id="b" y="120" width="200" height="200" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <!-- wrap pattern contents with a group, offsetting the y value removed from viewBox -->
    <g transform="translate(0, 200)">
        <rect class="st0" y="-200" width="200" height="200"/>
        <rect class="st0" y="-200" width="200" height="200"/>
        <g class="st1">
            <rect class="st2" y="-100" width="200" height="100"/>
        </g>
        <g class="st1">
            <rect class="st2" x="100" y="-200" width="100" height="200"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</pattern>
    
<pattern id="a" xlink:href="#b" patternTransform="matrix(.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -.014142 -16028 -559.29)">
</pattern>

<path class="st5" d="m87.5 87.5v23.1c0 3.5-2.6 6.4-6.1 6.8-21.7 2.6-42.3 0-50.3-1.2-2.1-0.3-3.6-2.1-3.6-4.2 0-5.6 0.1-16.7 0.5-24.4h23.5"/>

</svg>
```

Looks like it has been reported here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1193586